# unable to optimize trained tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Iam a beginner to tensorflow. I want to quantize a inception model that is already trained. i followed steps and ran following code:

```css
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference \
  --input=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output=tf_files/optimized_graph.pb \
  --input_names="input" \
  --output_names="final_result"
```

**but i am getting errors as such:**

```css
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_ma
in
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\opt
imize_for_inference.py", line 146, in <module>
    app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\
app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\opt
imize_for_inference.py", line 90, in main
    FLAGS.output_names.split(","), FLAGS.placeholder_type_enum)
  File "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\opt
imize_for_inference_lib.py", line 109, in optimize_for_inference
    placeholder_type_enum)
  File "C:\Users\Student\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\str
ip_unused_lib.py", line 83, in strip_unused
    raise KeyError("The following input nodes were not found: %s\n" % not_found)

KeyError: "The following input nodes were not found: {'input'}\n"
```

**please some one help me to resolve this issue.**

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
--input_names="input"
```

into

```
--input_names="Mul"
```

or if you are on windows, simply run the following in your terminal from your current working space

```
python -m tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference --input 
retrained_graph.pb --output optimized_graph.pb --input_names="Mul" -- 
output_names="final_result"
```

Comment: My problem is not solved. It is showing me this error nemo@nemo-X200MA:~$ python -m tensorflow.python.tools.optimize_for_inference --input output_graph.pb --output optimized_graph.pb --input_names="Mul" -- output_names="final_result" 
  raise KeyError("The following input nodes were not found: %s\n" % not_found)
KeyError: "The following input nodes were not found: set(['Mul'])\n"